Customize shadows for dark and light themes when use experimental_extendTheme in Material UI
I have a theme like this, created using experimental_extendTheme of MUI:
"use client";

import { experimental_extendTheme as extendTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { dark, light } from "./palettes";
import { typography } from "./typography";

export const createTheme = (direction: "rtl" | "ltr") => {
  return extendTheme({
    colorSchemes: {
      light: { palette: light },
      dark: { palette: dark },
    },
    typography: typography,
    direction,
    shadows: ? // how to create shadows for dark and light theme?
  });
};

Now I want to create shadows for this two dark and light themes, but there is no option to differentiate between different themes in this situation, Also I cannot access the selected mode when I am creating the theme to use it to create different shadows based on that! what should I do?
